# How can I store intent or screen progress on android local database?

Tags: java, android, json, android-intent, gson

I'm a beginner at android development. I'm currently creating a game like **4-Pics-1-Word** for my school project. It has 25 questions so I created 25 activities. I know this isn't the right method of doing this. Others have suggested that I should just change the pictures in `ImageView`. I tried to learn how to do that but I really don't understand it so I did this method. Now I'm stuck. This is how my game works. It is just like 4 pics 1 word but my prof told me that the activities must be randomized. I already randomized it. The only problem is I can't store the progress of the game on the android local database. I used `intent.putExtra` to send the information from the current activity to another activity. So basically after answering the previous activity then the previous activity must be removed from the list. I'm done with that already. I just can't find a way to store it on local database so when the user closes the game and opened it again the progress is saved. I tried this code below but the application won't open. It says **"Unfortunately stopped"**. Not sure where the problem is. Please help me. Thank you.

Here's the code for my **MainActivity**.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{

Button btnStart;
Context context;
SharedPreferences mPrefs = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor prefsEditor = mPrefs.edit();
Gson gson = new Gson();
ArrayList<Class> activityList


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Button btnStart = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnStart);
    String arrayStr = mPrefs.getString("MyObject","defValue");
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    activityList= gson.fromJson(arrayStr,new TypeToken<List<Class>>(){}.getType());
    //if the cache is null then new arraylist.
    if(activityList==null){
         // We are creating a list, which will store the activities that haven't been opened yet
        activityList = new ArrayList<>();
        activityList.add(first.class);
        activityList.add(second.class);
        activityList.add(third.class);
        activityList.add(fourth.class);
        activityList.add(fifth.class);
    }
    btnStart.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Random generator = new Random();
            int number = generator.nextInt(5) + 1;

            Class activity = null;

            switch(number) {
                case 1:
                    activity = first.class;
                    activityList.remove(first.class);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    activity = second.class;
                    activityList.remove(second.class);
                    break;
                case 3:
                    activity = third.class;
                    activityList.remove(third.class);
                    break;
                case 4:
                    activity = fourth.class;
                    activityList.remove(fourth.class);
                    break;
                default:
                    activity = fifth.class;
                    activityList.remove(fifth.class);
                    break;
            }

            Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), activity);
            intent.putExtra("ACTIVITY_LIST", activityList);
    String json = gson.toJson(activityList); // myObject - instance of MyObject
    prefsEditor.putString("MyObject", json);
    prefsEditor.commit();
    startActivity(intent);
        }}
```

and here's the code for my **first** activity:

```
public class first extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{
EditText etAnswer;
Button btnGo;
Context context;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_first);
    etAnswer = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etAnswer);
    btnGo = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnGo);
    btnGo.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch(v.getId()){
        case R.id.btnGo:
            String answer = etAnswer.getText().toString();
            if(answer.equals("Jose Rizal") ||  answer.equals("jose rizal") || answer.equals("Rizal") || answer.equals("rizal") ){
                AlertDialog.Builder dlgAlert  = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                dlgAlert.setMessage("The famous Rizal monument in Luneta was not the work of a Filipino but a Swiss sculptor named Richard Kissling?" +
                        "\n" +
                        "\n" +
                        "Source: http://www.joserizal.ph/ta01.html");
                dlgAlert.setTitle("Did you know that ...");
                dlgAlert.setPositiveButton("Next",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                ArrayList<Class> activityList = new ArrayList<>();
                                Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
                                activityList = (ArrayList<Class>) extras.get("ACTIVITY_LIST");

                                if(activityList.size() == 0) {
                                    Context context = getApplicationContext();
                                    CharSequence last = "Congratulations! You just finished the game! Please wait for the next update!";
                                    int durationFinal = Toast.LENGTH_LONG;

                                    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, last, durationFinal);
                                    toast.show();
                                } else {
                                    // Now, the random number is generated between 1 and however many
                                    // activities we have remaining
                                    Random generator = new Random();
                                    int number = generator.nextInt(activityList.size()) + 1;

                                    Class activity = null;

                                    // Here, we are checking to see what the output of the random was
                                    switch(number) {
                                        case 1:
                                            // We will open the first remaining activity of the list
                                            activity = activityList.get(0);
                                            // We will now remove that activity from the list
                                            activityList.remove(0);
                                            break;
                                        case 2:
                                            // We will open the second remaining activity of the list
                                            activity = activityList.get(1);
                                            activityList.remove(1);
                                            break;
                                        case 3:
                                            // We will open the third remaining activity of the list
                                            activity = activityList.get(2);
                                            activityList.remove(2);
                                            break;
                                        case 4:
                                            // We will open the fourth remaining activity of the list
                                            activity = activityList.get(3);
                                            activityList.remove(3);
                                            break;
                                        default:
                                            // We will open the fifth remaining activity of the list
                                            activity = activityList.get(4);
                                            activityList.remove(4);
                                            break;
                                    }

                                    // Note: in the above, we might not have 3 remaining activities, for example,
                                    // but it doesn't matter because that case wouldn't be called anyway,
                                    // as we have already decided that the number would be between 1 and the number of
                                    // activities left.


                                    // Starting the activity, and passing on the remaining number of activities
                                    // to the next one that is opened
                                    Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), activity);
                                    intent.putExtra("ACTIVITY_LIST", activityList);
                                    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                                    startActivity(intent);
                                }
                            }
                        });
                dlgAlert.setCancelable(true);
                dlgAlert.create().show();

            }else{
                Context context = getApplicationContext();
                CharSequence text = "Wrong! Try Again.";
                int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;

                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
                toast.show();
            }
            break;
    }
}}
```

and this is my **second** activity:

```
public class second extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{
EditText etAnswer;
Button btnGo;
Context context;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);
    etAnswer = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etAnswer);
    btnGo = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnGo);
    btnGo.setOnClickListener(this);
}
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch(v.getId()){
        case R.id.btnGo:
            String answer = etAnswer.getText().toString();
            if(answer.equals("Antonio Luna") || answer.equals("antonio luna") || answer.equals("Heneral Luna") || answer.equals("heneral luna") ){
                AlertDialog.Builder dlgAlert  = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                dlgAlert.setMessage("He is the younger brother of the famous Filipino painter Juan Luna who is known for his masterpiece Spoliarium." +
                        "\n" +
                        "\n" +
                        "Source: http://nobert-bermosa.blogspot.com/2011/05/70-interesting-facts-about-general.html");
                dlgAlert.setTitle("Did you know that ...");
                dlgAlert.setPositiveButton("Next",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                ArrayList<Class> activityList = new ArrayList<>();
                                Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
                                activityList = (ArrayList<Class>) extras.get("ACTIVITY_LIST");

                                if(activityList.size() == 0) {
                                    Context context = getApplicationContext();
                                    CharSequence last = "Congratulations! You just finished the game! Please wait for the next update!";
                                    int durationFinal = Toast.LENGTH_LONG;

                                    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, last, durationFinal);
                                    toast.show();
                                } else {
                                    // Now, the random number is generated between 1 and however many
                                    // activities we have remaining
                                    Random generator = new Random();
                                    int number = generator.nextInt(activityList.size()) + 1;

                                    Class activity = null;

                                    // Here, we are checking to see what the output of the random was
                                    switch(number) {
                                        case 1:
                                            // We will open the first remaining activity of the list
                                            activity = activityList.get(0);
                                            // We will now remove that activity from the list
                                            activityList.remove(0);
                                            break;
                                        case 2:
                                            // We will open the second remaining activity of the list
                                            activity = activityList.get(1);
                                            activityList.remove(1);
                                            break;
                                        case 3:
                                            // We will open the third remaining activity of the list
                                            activity = activityList.get(2);
                                            activityList.remove(2);
                                            break;
                                        case 4:
                                            // We will open the fourth remaining activity of the list
                                            activity = activityList.get(3);
                                            activityList.remove(3);
                                            break;
                                        default:
                                            // We will open the fifth remaining activity of the list
                                            activity = activityList.get(4);
                                            activityList.remove(4);
                                            break;
                                    }

                                    // Note: in the above, we might not have 3 remaining activities, for example,
                                    // but it doesn't matter because that case wouldn't be called anyway,
                                    // as we have already decided that the number would be between 1 and the number of
                                    // activities left.


                                    // Starting the activity, and passing on the remaining number of activities
                                    // to the next one that is opened
                                    Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), activity);
                                    intent.putExtra("ACTIVITY_LIST", activityList);
                                    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                                    startActivity(intent);
                                }
                            }
                        });
                dlgAlert.setCancelable(true);
                dlgAlert.create().show();

            }else{
                Context context = getApplicationContext();
                CharSequence text = "Wrong! Try Again.";
                int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;

                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
                toast.show();
            }
            break;
    }
}}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, _a specific problem or error_ and _the shortest code necessary_ to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ViewPager` to show  multiple  questions with one `Activity`  and if you  can't use `ViewPager` and go through multiple `Activitys` then you can store your  questions, answer  state using `SharedPrefrences` OR `ApplicationContext` or batter is you  should use `SQLite` database  to make your game.

Comment: I have no problem in storing the answers. My only problem is storing the progress. The current state of my game is when the user plays the game the progress is not saved so when the user opens the game again the game stars from the beginning again because I am only using `intent.putExtra` to send the progress to another activity.

Comment: That's why I mentioned SheardPrefrence , and SQLite  to store your  current state  rather passing one Activity  data to another using intent.putExtra. Because each time  you restart your game you can retrieve your data from either from SharedPrefrences or SQLite  when you stored your data.  And According your data you can open your game from previous state.

Comment: How can I open my game on my previous state? And also how can I store the ArrayList of Classes `ArrayList<Class>` on the SharedPreference?

Comment: You can not store `ArrayList` in to `SharedPrefrences` But you can store it in 'SQLite` by making Table or you should  convert `ArrayList` in String  Format and then you can store it in SharedPrefrences

Comment: I'm interested in storing it on SQLite. Can you teach me how can I store an ArrayList on SQLite? I know basic MySQL but I'm not familiar with SQLite

Comment: You can follow any tutorial. It's very simple to create and use databases.